# Create an error log file in php

Tags: php, mysql, error-log

I want an error log file attached to my application I have developed. My application is made in php mysql and I need that whatever error is found it should be displayed in a .txt file with full explanation like what is the error in which line number like that. I have no Idea how can I get that.

Can anyone help me creating this and changes do I have to make to get those error in my application. My server is an IIS server.

Comment: Use `try` `catch` and in catch log the error to the file where you want to write the error.

Comment: There are already log files being created by PHP/IIS that you should be able to look at. Are these not sufficient? Are you looking for a more custom logging facility? What have you looked at so far?

Comment: the error file inside Apache shows error off all other application projects error but I want particularly for this application how can I do that???

Answer (score 3):

First we have to see types of errors in PHP:

**Notices:** These are non-critical errors which PHP encounters while running a script. For example, a variable accessibility before it is declared.

**Warnings:** The are more serious errors. For example, using include()without the existence of the file.

**Fatal Errors:** These errors are critical errors. For example, creating an object of a non-existent class. These errors terminate the script’s execution immediately. These are intimated to the users.

Now, the process of Catching these 3 types of errors

```
//Setting for the PHP Error Handler
set_error_handler( call_back function or class );

//Setting for the PHP Exceptions Error Handler
set_exception_handler(call_back function or class);

//Setting for the PHP Fatal Error
register_shutdown_function(call_back function or class);
```

Whatever the function or class is described by user for tracing the error the following command is used:

```
 $debug = debug_backtrace();

 print_r($debug);
```

If you print the debug then it will show you the running process and file name, line number of the error.